# Environment variable dissapear after virtualenv deactivate

Tags: linux, django, environment-variables

I'm using environment variables for secrets in my Django app. But after `deactivate` command in virtual environment this variables disappear.

For set environment variables i'm using `export` command:

1)`source env/bin/activate`

2)`export DJANGO_DATABASE_PASSWORD='password'`

> ValueError: Value 'DATABASE_PASSWORD' is required to be set as the
>   environment variable 'DJANGO_DATABASE_PASSWORD'

Why this happening and how to avoid this behavior?

Comment: with what tool you are using virtual environment? Provide more info how you activating and deactivating it. And how you are calling your commands

Comment: This doesn't happen for me locally. How you are disabling virtualenv? with `deactivate`?

Comment: Yes, with deactivate, disable in question is my typo.

Comment: Why are you disabling the virtualenv at all?